# Cannot find symbol Model in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a simple test web app with Spring Boot 2. I get "cannot find symbol" for Model. Please see the print screen image. What am I doing wrong? My code is identical to a lecture I am following from Ken Kousen on O'rielly and I am using the same version. Thank you.

[image: 2]

Comment: You should import it.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels can you provide the duplicate? I searched for similar before asking. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Vusal. I had to include the following which is omitted from the lecture. import org.springframework.ui.Model;